# Laravel: Flash data in Blade file truncating double value

Tags: php, laravel-5

Double value when sent  to blade file in Laravel from controller function having 15 digits after decimal is automatically getting rounded off to only 6-7 digits after decimal when printed in blade file. Not getting the reason why is it happening so? I am sending data as follows:

```
    return redirect()->to('/list')->with('data_record', $data);
```

The code in view file (blade) that displays the data is as follows:

```
@foreach(session('data_record') as $item)
{{$item->lat}},{{$item->lng}} <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please show the code in your view that displays the truncated value.

Comment: I have edited the the question to show the view file code

Comment: i'd try `dd($data)` before your `return redirect()...` and see if all the data is there.

Comment: Yes I did that, all the data is there as it is, with accuracy of 15 digits after the decimal.

Comment: Which session driver are you using?  If using `database`, maybe something is wrong with the column definitions or something.

Comment: I am getting that value from database, the column is of type double as follows:           
            $table->double('lat',30,15)->nullable();
            $table->double('lng',30,15)->nullable();
Column is able to store data properly.

Comment: I was saying, maybe the column in your `sessions` table is configured incorrectly, not your `model` table.  If you are using `file` driver, this would be irrelevant anyway.

Does it work if you return `view` instead of `redirect` ?

Comment: I am using file driver